# finite Galois extension of K/$Q$ of index $>2$ prove that there exists field L s.t .$Q$ ⊊ L ⊆ $R$ ∩ K

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Where $R$ is the real number field.

I am having trouble proving this statement, honestly i don't even have an idea where to start.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: consider the subgroup $H$ of the Galois group generated by $z \longmapsto \overline{z}$.

Comment: I highly recommend that you add some context or otherwise improve the question according to [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). My (now deleted) answer relies on a few pieces of Galois theory, but to turn it into useful answer that would benefit other users as well we need to know more about background of field theory. Also, 1) we will not answer copy/pasted assignment exercises without a dialogue, 2) it would not surprise me, if this very question had been handled here already. Did you search the site?

Comment: This can be simply restated as: "prove that $\Bbb R \cap K \neq \Bbb Q$".